# WSO2 ESB. Accessing Secure Vault programmaticaly

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am implementing handler for REST API in Java (`org.apache.synapse.rest.Handler` interface). And there is a case, when I need to access Secure Vault and get a value.
I know that you are able to achieve this by `expression="wso2:vault-lookup('YOUR.KEY.HERE')"` in sequence, but can't find api to do this in handler. I believe that `org.apache.synapse.MessageContext` can help, but not sure how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below code segment in the custom handler.

```
 public String getSecretPassword(String alias, MessageContext messageContext){
     RegistrySecretRepository regRepo = new RegistrySecretRepository();
     regRepo.setSynCtx(messageContext);
     return regRepo.getSecret(alias); 
    }
```

Dependency for pom.xml, the version needs to be changed according to your product version.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wso2.carbon</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.mediation.security</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.0</version>
</dependency
```

Please refer - http://malantech.blogspot.com/2016/10/basic-authentication-handler-with.html

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe you will not be able to get the value of the security vault directly from your handler so I advise you to recover the password and put it in a property and inside your handler to retrieve the property.

```
<property name="passwordvault"
                   expression="wso2:vault-lookup('YOUR.KEY.HERE')"
                   scope="default"/>
```

And use the `MessageContext` to get the propertie like this:

```
context.getProperty("passwordvault");
```

Comment: But this is not a property actually, I need a vault entry.
I still tried your solution, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @КонстантинТокарев I edited my answer, maybe this "workaround" work for you.

Comment: No, it won't. I would have used this approach if I used custom mediator. But Handler is invoked before the API sequence, so this prop won't be in a scope at the moment

Comment: I think you can not access the security vault outside of a sequence. At least I never tried and I did not see it working either.

Comment: Well I've found a way to do this, posted the answer

Comment: Well, I saw your answer and you're using it the way I told you, as I told you, you would have to use a sequence to be able to retrieve and put in a property.

Comment: My solution is a bit different from yours, but yeah, it helped me to figure out mine.

Answer (score 0):

And I will answer my own question.

I've created a dummy sequence and placed it into Registry

```
<sequence name="SecureVaultSeq" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
<property expression="wso2:vault-lookup('MY.PASS')" name="NAME"
        scope="default" type="STRING"
        xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:ns3="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
</sequence>
```

Then in my handler i retrieved it like this:

```
messageContext.getConfiguration().getSequence("conf:Resources/sequences/SecureVaultSeq.xml").mediate(messageContext);
key = (String) messageContext.getProperty("NAME");
```

Hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

That's just a workaround which is not advisable , i believe you can try below code as i have used similar earlier as well and it worked

```
<property expression="wso2:vault-lookup('ei.training.userid')" name="UserID" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <log>
                <property expression="wso2:vault-lookup('ei.training.userid')" name="UID"/>
            </log>
```